# Allow scripts to read a file but prevent users from viewing the file directly

Tags: php, linux

Lets say I have a plain text file `example.txt` and I have a PHP script on my web-server `readfile.php`.

What I want to be able to do is to prevent users from typing `http://www.example.com/example.txt` and looking at the text file directly but I still want people to be able to load `http://www.example.com/readfile.php` which reads from the file `example.txt` and does something with it (possibly displays the contents of the file).

Also, if this can be done, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You mean "...want people to be able to load http://www.example.com/readfile.php" not "readfile.txt".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do.

There are two main ways to stop users from accessing `example.txt`. The first is to put it in a folder outside your web folder (Usually called `www` or `public_html`), the second is to put a `.htaccess` file in the folder with your example.txt script which blocks access to the file altogether. The `.htaccess` would look like

```
<files "example.txt"> 
deny from all 
</files>
```

But you could change `example.txt` to something like `*.txt` if you wanted to block all `.txt` files in the folder.

Then you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in your `readfile.php` to get the contents of the text file, or if you just want to output the file you can use [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: +1 for putting the file in the web directory and using .htaccess. Thanks.

Comment: I added the .htaccess file, however I get an error when trying to call file_get_contents() :: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. Do I have to change any permissions for php to access to file? I also tried using cUrl with no luck.

Comment: In your .htaccess use:  
SecFilterEngine Off
<files "example.txt"> 
deny from all 
</files>

Answer (score 9):

Just store the files you don't want publicly accessible **outside the webroot**.

```
/home
   example.txt
   /www
      readfile.php
```

If `/home/www/` is your public webroot folder, any file above it is not accessible through the web server. `readfile.php` can still access the file perfectly fine at `../example.txt` though.

Comment: WOW...why didn't I think of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the files in the webroot, then put the files in a folder and deny access to that folder. If you are using apache, make a .htaccess file in the folder and type in `deny from all`

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar where the files contain extremely sensitive information and I only want validated users to be able to retrieve the file through an HTTPS connection.

What I did was this:

I put the files in a directory path that is outside the scope of what the web server (Apache, for me) can see. Therefore, there are no possible URLs that will result in the file being served up directly by the web server. Then I created a script that allows users to login, click on the file they want, and then the PHP script reads the file, puts the appropriate headers, and then streams the file to the user's computer.

Of course, the script that shows the user the list of files and the script that streams the file out to the user must have at least read access to the files in the path where they are being stored.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file "example.txt" outside of the public folder and read from readfile.php like `$content = file_get_contents("../example.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

You can call a file like this and the people don't see the filename:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

(source: php.net)

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack - rename your file to ".cannotReadFileWithDOT". he server will close reading files with a dot at the beginning of the name, but your scripts will be able to read them. The plus is that the apache and nginx servers out of the box are configured to prohibit reading files with a dot at the beginning of the name.