# Sending mail from script with email list file

Tags: php, email, text-files

back again. I wanted to know if there's anyway to specify a particular file for the recipients so that it sends to the emails in the file instead of having to put a comma between all of the emails. Thanks

```
 <?php 
$name = $_POST['Chase'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'my message';
$from = 'From: email@domain'; 
$to = 'Email.txt(herE)';
$subject = 'hi world';
$body = "From: $name\r\n E-Mail: $email\r\n Message:\r\n $message";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: email@domain' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { echo "Error Sending Email!"; }

else

{ echo "Mail sent!"; }
```

Comment: Sure, you could use `$to = file_get_contents('Email.txt');`. Just remember that the names would need to be separated by commas or semicolons in that file.

Comment: sidenote: since you're sending as HTML, `\r\n` will be included in the message as string literals. Use `<br>`'s.

Comment: you'd need to post an example of your text file too, replacing actual emails with made-up ones, plus showing us what you tried as an effort would be nice too.

Comment: don't use mail(), then. use phpmailer or swiftmailer, both of which make it trivial to send to multiple recipients.

Comment: a database would be better also. *no fuss, no muss* and safer. text files can be a pain.

Comment: @OP, let us know if the answers worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this :-
**Note** :- Make sure you From email is active when you're hosting this on a server accessible via domain.

```
$name = "some name";
    $email = "test@gmail.com";
    $message = 'my message';
    $subject = 'hi world';
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: youremail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $handle = fopen("emails.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
           if (!mail($line, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
            { 
                echo "Error Sending Email!"; 
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "Mail sent!"; 
            }


            } //while
```

fclose($handle);
            }//if - outer
        else
        {
            echo "can't open file";
        }

**emails.txt**

```
test@gmail.com
foo@gmail.com
```

You can add more emails to the text file, without adding a comma.
P.s :- I'd highly recommend you to use phpmailer.

---

**File security**

Make sure that you protect the text file through `.htaccess`, this is very important.

Here is a Q&A on the subject on Stack:

- [Allow scripts to read a file but prevent users from viewing the file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978036/)

You can further your research by using "how to protect a text file php" as keywords in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Sure... but let's just hope the OP will take the necessary precautions to safeguard that text file ;-) Personally, I'd use a db for this instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Agree for the most part :)
I myself use DB in these kind of situations. Because these type of situations (sending same email to multiple people) occur generally when you're updating clients from a client database and letting them know about some updates.

Comment: Just to let you know that, I tested what you posted and it didn't work for me. Maybe the OP tried it also, but that I can't speak for them. Best you go over it and test it out. I did what I could to modify it on my end. I'll wait another 1/2 hour or so also, maybe the server's queuing's off. I'll let you know if it did make it though, but do try and test it on your side.

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Just updated my code. Had a few typo's. Tested this code for 2 emails in the `emails.txt` file and it worked fine.
One thing you need to take care here is, that if you're testing this file from your server, then, in the `From: ` (the headers), you need to put an email which is active on your server. So suppose your domain name is test.com, and your email is `no-reply@test.com` (Which is working), then From will `From : no-reply@test.com`. Then only the php mail function works in some cases, personal experience :)